# Pass parameters from as_json to model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Controller:

```
user = User.find(params[:id])
respond_with({:posts => @posts.as_json})
```

Model:

```
def as_json(options = {})
  {
    name: self.name,
    ...
  }
end
```

I want to pass parmeters like `params[:id]` to the `as_json` function to change things in the JSON display.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, as_json does take an options hash, so I suppose you could call it using

```
respond_with({:posts => @posts.as_json(:params => params)})
```

You'd then be able to reference the params in the definition of `as_json`:

```
def as_json(options = {})
  params = options[:params] || {}
  {
    name: self.name,
    params_id: params[:id]
    ...
  }
end
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think this works.  ActiveSupport (atleast in rails4) specifically does not pass options to ActiveModel as_json. See here: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3762ee0baa2285bdc4a76d4d492fbe34a10cdc3a/activesupport/lib/active_support/json/encoding.rb#L299 - I'm curious if there is another approach

Comment: Sorry, let me clarify: this won't work if you call to_json on a high level object, and there are nested attributes/objects that will be serialized and thus have as_json called on it as well.